# How to type with Hebrew Nikkud on an iPad

Tags: ipad

Is there a way to type with Hebrew nikkud/ niqqud (diacritical vowels) on an iPad?
There is a Davka app which allows you to type with nikkud within the app, but I'm looking for a way to type text with nikkud into a graphics app or into the web browser.

I am especially looking for a way to insert the nikkud/diacritical characters for free.

Comment: which os version are you using?

Comment: Can't you copy/paste from the Davka app?

Comment: Using OSX, select Show Keyboard Viewer under the flag menu, press the ALT key and you will be a full mapping of the NIKUD marks. The problem is that the iOS Hebrew keyboard does not have an ALT key. I continue looking for a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Janet  What is your problem?  You just use the Davka Nikud app.  http://davka.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=205

Answer (score 1):

If you have iOS 8, there is Davka Nikud

https://itunes.apple.com/app/davka-nikud/id917653147

Answer (score 1):

[Google Keyboard for IOS](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/gboard-the-google-keyboard/id1091700242) has [Niqqud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud).

Answer (score 0):

By pressing alt/option while typing certain keys, you can get the following nikkud:

' = ָ 
ו = וּ

שׂ = ש

But I can't seem to figure out the exact pattern.

Comment: That's for a Mac. This question is about iOS, whose Hebrew keyboard is slightly less friendly.

Comment: @user24601 I did find them on iOS, on my iPad. I was systematically hitting every key on my bluetooth iPad keyboard, and this is what I discovered. But there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to which keys worked with alt/option and which didn't. Can you help me figure that out?

Comment: @LN6595 For the keymapping of a bluetooth keyboard, you just activate the Hebrew layout you want on a Mac running OS X and then use Keyboard Viewer to see what happens when you press the alt key.  But Davka NIkud should work with all apps that support Hebrew without any need to copy/paste.